# How to fix 'Unclosed quotation mark after the character string \')\'.' error

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm generating a dynamic sql query based on some user input. Here is the code that prepares the query:

```
var preparedParamValues = paramValues.map(paramValue => `'${paramValue}'`).join(',');

var sql = `INSERT INTO [DB] (${paramNames}) VALUES (${preparedParamValues})`;
```

When I send the following string to the DB it throws the below error:
`'They're forced to drive stupid cars.'`

I get an error :

> 'Unclosed quotation mark after the character string \')\'.'

I'm trying to find a way to escape all those characters but I don't understand the error or at least the last part of it with all the symbols.

Comment: Simple, if you want to use a single quote within a string in SQL you have to escape it - which means doubling it.

Comment: always use Replace(preparedParamValues, "'", "''")
i.e. replace the simple quote with two simple quotes before execution. 
not sure about the syntax in js

Comment: Can you not use [replacements](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/raw-queries/#replacements) (or similar, if using some other binding) rather than reinventing SQL Injection problems in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two single quotes when a single quote appears in the string:

```
'They''re forced to drive stupid cars.'
```